# In how many ways can six types of objects be distributed to three distinct zones if there are two objects of each type?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a hard time solving this question, for some reason I can't get my head around it. Here it goes:

There are 3 different zones and 6 different type of object of which there are 2 object of each type (12 objects in total). How many different ways can these objects be distributed among the zones?

- The ordering of the objects within the zones are not significant but the ordering of the zones are
- each object must be within a zone
- there is no limitation on how many objects a zone can contain and empty zones are permitted

my brute-force approach:
step 1:
find all the combinations of how many objects can a zone have:

```
z1  z2  z3
12  0   0
11  1   0
10  2   0
10  1   1
9   3   0
9   2   1   
8   4   0
8   3   1
8   2   2
7   5   0
7   4   1
7   3   2
6   6   0
6   5   1
6   4   2
6   3   3
5   5   1
5   4   2
5   3   3
4   4   4
```

step2: find how many different ways the object types can be distrubuted among these. I have actually solved it for 2 types of objects but not 6 because it gets way too complex for the 6 object types.

Comment: More generalized version: https://www.quora.com/2n-objects-of-each-of-three-kinds-are-given-to-two-persons-so-that-each-person-gets-3n-objects-Prove-that-this-can-be-done-in-3n-2-2n-1-ways-Ive-solution-but-Im-not-able-to-understand-it-Could-you-please-elaborate?ch=3&share=a95036f1&srid=u23rsB

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: @MushuNrek I solved it by bruteforce but Im looking for a more elegant way to solve it. I found some generative software to solve the problem but I would rather prefer a mathematical one.

Comment: Hint: each of the six types of object can be distributed independently of the others, since it does not matter in what order objects are assigned to a zone.

Comment: If I understand it well, you can decide independently how to order the zones and then how to distribute the object into the zones. As far as I am concerned, I do not see in which way the type of an object has an influence of where to put it.. Is the question complete? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempt.  Also, you seem to misunderstood what Jaap Scherphuis said.  In how many ways can you distribute objects of the first type?  Multiply this answer by the number of ways you can distribute objects of the second type.  Continue.

Comment: @MushuNrek the constraint that there are only 12 objects is the problem here, you cannot distribute them independently. for example lets say that there are 9 objects in z1 2 in z2 and 1 in z3. lets take z2 and z3 for consideration and ignore z1 as it will take the rest of the objects. for z3 there can only be 6 objects there if we ignore the case that 2 objects of the same type is in z2.how can I resolve the case that there is no more of the type of object left in the pool to distribute to the zones?

Comment: @AliNuriŞeker I still don't understand how the type of the object is involved in the problem... We can have both object of one type in the same zone? As to your solution: it seems to me as if you had forgotten to take into account the order of the zones. That would need a third step I suspect.

Comment: @MushuNrek difference between object types is what generates a different state in the system. lets assume 11 1 0 for this there are 6 different acceptable distributions, because 6 different objects can be put in zone 2. and yes there must be a multiple number of same objects in at least one of the zones as all the 12 objects must be in a zone.
as for the third step just multiply the sum with 6 that is the way the zones can be distributed. (z1 z2 z3) ,(z2 z1 z3) (z3 z2 z1) (z3 z1 z2) (z1 z3 z2)

Comment: What is your solution for one type of object?  In how many ways can two indistinguishable objects be placed in three zones?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I elaborated on your hint and I concluded that for each object type since there are 3 different zones and object count is 2 there are 6 different states. since there are 6 different objects does that mean there is 6^6 different solutions?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig solution for 1 type of object is stated in the above comment, for your second question: exactly.

Comment: Your response to JaapScherphuis is correct.  There are indeed $\binom{2 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1}  = 6$ ways to distribute two indistinguishable objects to three zones, so your answer $6^6$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's begin with a simpler question:

> In how many ways can two indistinguishable objects be placed in three distinct zones?

Let $x_i$ be the number of objects placed in the $i$th zone, where $1 \leq i \leq 3$.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 2$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of $3 - 1 = 2$ addition signs in a row of two ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 + +$$
corresponds to the solution $(2, 0, 0)$, while
$$+ 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $(0, 1, 1)$.  The number of such solutions is
$$\binom{2 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{4}{2} = 6$$
since we must choose which $3 - 1 = 2$ of the $2 + 3 - 1 = 4$ positions required for two ones and two addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

> In how many ways can six types of objects be distributed to three distinct zones if there are two objects of each type?

As Jaap Scherphuis pointed out in the comments, each type of object can be distributed independently of the others.  Since the two objects of each of the six types of objects can be distributed to the three zones in six ways, there are $6^6$ possible distributions.